# Removing observations based on duplication between 2 data.frames

Tags: r

Quick question that is similar to previous questions in SO, but not quite.

Let's say I have two dataframes.  I want to delete the observations in one dataframe (`keep`) if the same `id` variable appears in the other dataframe (`delete`).

For example, `keep` might look like this:

```
id   var
1    dog
2    dog
3    cat
4    dog
5    dog
6    cat
```

And then `delete` might look like this:

```
id   var2
1    blue
3    red
5    blue
```

The desired outcome I want is:

```
id  var
2   dog
4   dog
6   cat
```

I have a feeling that this is rather elementary (maybe using `data.table` and `match`, or `!duplicate`?) but I can't quite figure out how to keep `var` and just remove based on `id` variables. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may work:

```
keep[!(keep$id %in% delete$id),]

  id var
2  2 dog
4  4 dog
6  6 cat
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = read.table(text = 'id   var
1    dog
2    dog
3    cat
4    dog
5    dog
6    cat', header = T)
df2 = read.table(text = 'id   var2
1    blue
3    red
5    blue', header = T)

library(data.table)

# convert to data.table, set the key correctly
dt1 = data.table(df1, key = 'id')
dt2 = data.table(df2, key = 'id')

# yep, *that* simple (and also will be very fast)
dt1[!dt2]
#   id var
#1:  2 dog
#2:  4 dog
#3:  6 cat
```